# How did Thor return to Earth in The Avengers?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-avengers, thor

In ***Thor***, it's stated that the Bifrost Bridge is how Asgardians travel between the worlds. When Thor destroys the Bridge at the end of his first film, Loki and Thor have the following exchange.

> **LOKI**: Stop! What are you doing?! If you destroy the Bridge, you'll never see her again!
>
> **THOR**: Forgive me.

<sup>*Thor* transcript via [The Internet Movie Script Database](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Thor.html)</sup>

[image: Destroyed Bifrost Bridge]

If the bridge was destroyed, how does Thor return to Earth in ***The Avengers***? Is there any in-universe explanation?

Comment: In the Thor comics when I was a kid, Thor couldn't reach the Bifrost for some reason. He summoned a storm to create a rainbow. The other explanation is better but mine uses comic logic.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> **LOKI: Oh, you should thank me. With the Bifrost gone how much dark energy did the Allfather have to muster to conjure you here? Your precious Earth.**

<sup>*The Avengers* transcript via [The Internet Movie Script Database](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Avengers,-The-(2012).html)</sup>

While it's never *explicitly* explained in *The Avengers* how Thor returned to Earth, Loki implies that Odin used dark energy to send him back.

This is confirmed in the prelude comic for *Thor: The Dark World*, where Odin uses dark magic to send Thor to Earth/Midguard after seeing that Loki was planning on stealing the Tesseract.

[image: Panel from Thor: The Dark World Prelude]

According to [alexwlchan on Science Fiction and Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/39910/79413), in the second issue of the same comic, Thor and Heimdall use the power of the Tesseract to rebuild the Bifrost Bridge.

We see this newly rebuilt bridge in *Thor: The Dark World*, which is presumably how Thor returns to Earth in each subsequent movie after *The Avengers*.

[image: Rebuilt Bifrost Bridge in Thor: Dark World]

Comment: Why is this answer attracting so many DVs?  Seems like a well-researched and well stated answer to me.

Comment: @Steve-O I'd also like to know why that is. Is it because a similar question was asked on Sci-Fi?

Comment: That might be a reason to close the question as a duplicate (although I don't think even that's done cross-site.)  DVs should only be reflective of the quality of the question or answer to which they are applied (ie: lack of research, etc.)  MOst notably they are NOT supposed to be used as a "I disagree with this answer" button... if someone has a different answer, that's why the site allows multiple answers.